# WebClient.UploadValues() on Win Server 2008 - underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, post, windows-server-2008, webclient

I have a C# app where I send some request through https with post values. Here is the code:

```
private string _getResponseString(string url, NameValueCollection postData)
{
    byte[] response = null;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
            delegate { return true; };
        response = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", postData);
    }
    string responseStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
    return responseStr;
}
```

I tested it on many, many computers and it works fine. Unfortunately I have to use it also on Windows Server 2008 R2 and there is the problem. When it comes to `UploadValues` - the unhandled exception occurs - `The underlying connections was closed`.

Why it's not working only on Win Server? How to make it work?